# How do I use the mailTo protocol on in C# for a sharepoint web part?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, mailto

I've been trying to use the mail to protocol in my C# code - but its not working for me as everytime I press the button that is supposed to run the mailto code - the page refreshes instead and the outlook new message window does not open

My code is the following

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:"+email);
```

`"email"` above is a string object that is retrieved from a sharepoint list.

Comment: "page refreshes": is this a asp.net app? If so, where do you think that "mailto" process is started?

Comment: I think you need to explain more what you are trying to do. Is the c# running on the client computer or on a server? I'm not too familiar with sharepoint but I'd assume a web part is something on a web page so the c# wouldn't be running on the client. you might just want a standard anchor tag with an appropriately set href...

Answer (score 2):

Given your *"mailto:"+email* code fragment I am assuming that what you really want is this:

You want the user on your website to press a button which opens a new Outlook message with your E-Mail address, correct?

No need to use server side C# for this, as this is regular HTML and the default e-mail client is handling the `mailto:` protocol (just like your browser handles the `http:` protocol).

All you need to do is to have something like this:
`<a href="mailto:mymail@...com">Mail me</a>` on your site and once the user clicks this link the default mail program (might not be outlook) will handle the mailto link. You could also do this via a button.